# What is the difference between <stdin> and <STDIN>?

Tags: perl, perl-module

When I use `<stdin>` in Perl module (`*.pm`) files it's not reading input from the keyboard, but when I use `<STDIN>`  in the same place it works fine.

Why is it not getting input when I use `<stdin>`?

Comment: `stdin`:  Gotta love undocumented features.  Stick with `STDIN`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`STDIN` is the documented filehandle. There exists `stdin` as well, which is aliased to `STDIN`, but it only works in the `main::` package: `main::stdin` is the same as `main::STDIN` (as documented in [perlop - Perl operators and precedence](http://p3rl.org/perlop)).

In a package, therefore,

```
package My::Package;
sub xx {
    print while <stdin>;
}
```

`stdin` is interpreted as `My::Package::stdin`, which doesn't exist. You can use `main::stdin` from a package, but using the standard `STDIN` (which always points to `main::STDIN`, even from a package) is much cleaner.

Answer (score 12):

Didn't know about this, but found it documented in a throw-away paragraph in [`perlop`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlop.pod#I-O-Operators)

> The filehandles `STDIN`, `STDOUT`, and `STDERR` are predefined. (The filehandles `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` will also work except in packages, where they would be interpreted as local identifiers rather than global.) Additional filehandles may be created with the open() function, amongst others. See perlopentut and "open" in perlfunc for details on this.

Comment: Why would anyone know this?

Comment: I'm actually trying to think what the point of doing it in the first place would be. I mean, I could just about see why having a lowercase alias might make some sense, but not one with different behaviour.

Comment: It's probably a historical thing that's older than packages, and no one was bothered enough to fix its behaviour when packages were introduced.

Comment: Holy crup!  I had learned Perl in the version 4 days I thought I was pretty conversant with the docs and sundry historical cruft, but this one is news to me...

Comment: @choroba IMHO the only sensible fix would be dropping `<stdin>` (which could be a compatibility problem, so let's forget it). Its only use is TMTOWTDI.